# Is Intel Core-M virtualization usable?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, battery

I'm asking this question here because noone will let me try installing Virtualbox on an Intel Core-M "uncooled" machine without purchasing it.

I previously purchased an Intel i3 with 4GB RAM a couple of years ago because it was marked as supporting VT-x.  While the device does run my various VMs (Windows modern.ie VMs and Linux), it does seem to make the processor work very hard at doing so, which causes the system to stall occasionally and run very slowly at other times.

However, I'm regularly travelling for long periods of time, so battery life is also important to me.  I carry 3 batteries with me at the moment, which provides me with approximately 12 hours of use.

The 4W TDP of the Intel Core-M improves the battery life significantly while also providing VT-x (unlike the Atoms).  The concern I have is that the Core-M (particularly in "uncooled" environments) may have the same problem as my existing i3 and cap the processing speed when using VT-x under load.

Is the Intel Core-M (2 cores/4 threads) usable as a host for virtualization with Virtualbox and/or does it get hot/burn through the battery life as a result?

Comment: VT-X does help *somewhat* and is essential in some cases, but its really a function of quite a few things. I've got a celeron/atom that does fine with vt-x, and kvm. It would also depend on how 'heavy' the guest VM is and other factor. I'm not sure the question is really generally answerable

Comment: The general case is difficult, yes, but I'm more about minima.  Even basic VMs (like a fresh install of Windows 7) seems to make the i3 quite upset.

Comment: I run small ubuntu VMs on a bay trail nuc. It struggles with windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is usable but it's going to depend on what you want to do and which model you have (list of models here: http://ark.intel.com/products/family/83613/Intel-Core-M-Processors)

How many VMs will you be running, what will they do? You can get relatively cheap quad core processors which will perform better as well so maybe look in to them.

VT-X is more important than VT-D

As mentioned in the good comment below "VT-D wouldn't be necessary on a laptop - its a feature mainly useful for PCI-e passthrough"

Comment: I'm specifically looking at the M-5Y71 in an Asus T300 Chi.  The chip itself  is a 2.9GHz but apparently "uncooled" it only gets to 1.2GHz.   I can't seem to find a quad-core Atom with VT-x and VT-d or is VT-d not necessary?

Comment: VT-D wouldn't be necessary on a laptop - its a feature mainly useful for PCI-e passthrough